# Why doesn't my form submission code execute?

Tags: php, forms, http-post

I've checked other threads, but I can't find a solution.

I'm trying to get my PHP code to echo back to me to say that it works. I am using WAMP.

Code:

```
<html>
<title>Login</title>
<form method="post">
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['login_button'])){
        echo "Clicked";
    }

?>
User Name
<br>
<input type="text" name="username" />
<br>
<br>
Password
<br>
<input type="password" name="password" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" name="login_button" value="Login" />

</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `var_dump($_POST);` before the condition and show us the output?

Comment: Says array (size=0) empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you are using the wrong `type` for your button. When you want your button to cause your form to send data to the server, you need to use the `submit` type. This will tell the browser to send the form data back to the server when the button is clicked. The `button` type is mostly used for browser-based javascript code. That's why it doesn't do anything when you click it.

I just copied your exact code and changed `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. After I changed that, it worked.

Comment: Then the box turns into a box instead of a button?

Comment: Based on the HTML you provided, it shouldn't change the appearance. It will still be a button, the only difference is that it has the ability to submit the form.

Comment: Lol, Thanks! I miss typed Submit, By typing sumbit

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<input type="button" name="login_button" value="Login" />
```

To

```
<input type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login" />
```

Comment: Then the box turns into a box instead of a button?

Comment: @PaulBrennan it remains a button, but this time it submits the form.

Comment: Lol, Thanks! I miss typed Submit, By typing sumbit

Answer (score 0):

Check with `var_dump( $_POST )` to see what are you getting after form submission.

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last input to a submit instead of a button and if that does not work change the

```
$_POST
```

to

```
$_REQUEST
```